# Why doesn't the concept of employee engagement work in practice?

Tags: labor-economics, labor-cost

The concept of employee engagement looks like an overwhelming obvious way of improving business performance, yet since the mid-nineties, and after spending billions on engagement improvement systems, employee engagement is almost exactly where it started at 30%/70% (Gallup). Why?